# Compile .Jar to Unix Command line tool

Tags: java, macos, unix, jar, terminal

I have a .jar file and I would like it to run like a unix/Mac OS X executable so that it can be placed in /usr/local/bin and I can run it from terminal as I would run any other command written in c. I do not want a .app I just want a simple command line tool that I can run in terminal without using the java command, since it isn't practical for releasing my tool.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a wrapper class in c++ that will call the java program.

[run jar file from c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749173/run-jar-file-from-c) 
[Using JNI to execute a java jar from a C++ program, using g++ or eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560572/using-jni-to-execute-a-java-jar-from-a-c-program-using-g-or-eclipse)